# How do I close the Review Answer / Review Question popup?

Tags: support, review

I recently received the Strunk & White badge on Gaming, which has unlocked the "review" ability on the site.  After clicking Review Answer (or Review Question), if I decide to give the answer an up / down vote or if I decide to do nothing at all, I'm not certain how to clear the pop-up off the page.

Refreshing the page is an option, but seems cumbersome.  I've tested on the ancient version of IE at work (IE 7.0 / Windows XP) as well as on Safari at home, but I haven't seen any way to clear the popup once I've reviewed the answer or question.  Am I missing something obvious?

[image: I hear people like freehand circles...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to hide the posts you have already reviewed is to refresh the page. That is true for any review page except the "close" tab, where the question is automatically hidden when you vote to close it. (You don't see that tab because you are not a 10k user.)

To notice that there isn't any popup appearing when you review a post; the page content is expanded to show you the post as it is formatted in the question page, some more links that allows you to operate on the post, and (if the post is an answer) the content of the question for which the answer is.